# Radio button intercepting unchecked event in Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button, angular4-forms

I am writing an Angular component which uses radio button (Need to use default radio buttons due to project constraints).

I need to print the value of the radio button (whether it is checked or unchecked). Like following:

```
<input type="radio"  (change)="onUpdate($event)">
<p>{{isActive}}</p>
```

In the component something like this:

```
onUpdate(event) {
    this.isActive = event.target.checked;
}
```

But this doesn't work as the change event is not triggered when the radio button is unchecked. Is there any way to intercept the event when the radio button is unchecked?

Please help. I am stuck. **[Dummy app link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu)**

**Edit: What I am trying to do**

I am trying to write a custom radio button so that I can styles it on my own. I cannot write a `radio-group` component. Hence I need a wrapper component around the default one. Something like [Stackblitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu). I need the unchecked event because I have some custom element which has to be notified about this. Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you add an `[(ngModel)]` attribute to the radio button instead of checking for `event.target.checked`?

Comment: Did you find any solution? If you have a solution in anytime, please share that here. I am also searching the solution for it ...

Comment: Nope apparently there is no solution for this. You can end up using a radio group instead of a radio control.

Answer (score 0):

Use a checkbox, style it like a radio button. Seems to be the easiest solution and of course use ng-model instead of onChange.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace (change) with (click), because every click on the radio button is a change anyway.

```
<input type="radio" (click)="onUpdate($event)">
<p>{{isActive}}</p>
```

The above is a solution, but I'd use this:

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="isActive">
<p>{{isActive}}</p>
```

It binds your radio button to your isActive property, so it changes dynamically with clicking.

Comment: Okay may be i wasnt clear .. My requirement is something like this . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu . You can see the value doesnt not change when it is unchecked. Is there any way to achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

So using two radio buttons got this working for me, let me know if you can model this for your application.

```
<input type="radio" name="button" [value]="checked" (change)="checked=!checked">
<input type="radio" name="button" [value]="!checked" (change)="checked=!checked">
<p>{{checked}}</p>
```

I am setting `checked` to false by default in my component.

Comment: Okay may be i wasnt clear .. My requirement is something like this . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu . You can see the value doesnt not change when it is unchecked. Is there any way to achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to adjust this logic with your code? Checking some new `radio` will `uncheck` other and we can keep track of this behavior.

```
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="one" [(ngModel)]="isActive">
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="two" [(ngModel)]="isActive"> 
  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="three" [(ngModel)]="isActive">
</p>

<p>{{isActive}}</p>
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qteeld)

Comment: Okay may be i wasnt clear .. My requirement is something like this . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu . You can see the value doesnt not change when it is unchecked. Is there any way to achive this ?

Comment: You'r `stackblitz` link is empty. Maybe you forgot to save !

Comment: Oooooopsie...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2wnnu .. Updated it..